# How to email an HTML table using a button

Tags: javascript, html, email

Sorry but I am new to HTML so my code may be very messy but I am making an HTML table to use as an online To do list for daily tasks,
however we need to be able to email this out as proof that we have done them,

I have started to create the table and before I finish it I just want to get the code in for emailing it.
The idea is that as you complete a task you will tick it as complete, then at the end of the day you put in an email address and click a button to email the  to that address,

so far I have:

```html
<head>
  <style>
    table,
    th,
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    th,
    td {
      padding: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr align="center">
      <td>Complete</td>
      <td>Time</td>
      <td>Duty Manager Task</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <br />
      </td>
      <td>08:00</td>
      <td>Login to <a href="Link to internal site" target="_blank">TFS</a> & <a href="link to internal site" target="_blank">SNOW</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input name="emails" type="text" maxlength=256 "></input></td>
<td><input class="form" type="submit"  value="Email Table"></input></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You need to learn about forms, a server side programming language and multipart MIME emails. It's far too broad a topic for a Stackoverflow question.

Comment: See also: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Use phpmailer for mailing to user.  [phpmailer ] (http://phpmailer.worxware.com/)